# How to allow Tkinter GUI to detect key presses when not selected

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, keypress

I am trying to make a full GUI, for A game borderlands 2, however it only detects my key presses when the tkinter box is selected (in focus). In a game this is not happening, so I need a way for tkinter to detect my key presses while not selected. 
This is the code so far. It is not finished, ignore the "Auto Exec" and "Auto Exit" the problem is "Auto Reload". Clicking once will turn it ON and again will turn it OFF. Just choose any number (1-4) for the weapon slot, does not affect the error.

```
from easygui import *
from pyautogui import *
from time import *
import os
from tkinter import *
count = 1
slot = "0"
allowReload, allowExit = False, False
def poop():
    sleep(3)
    print("poop")
def countdown(count):
    autoexecB.config(text = count)
    if count == 2:
        autoexecB.config(bg = "orange")
    if count == 1:
        autoexecB.config(bg = "yellow")
    if count == 0:
        autoexecB.config(text = "Running...", bg = "#44ff00")
    if count > -1:
        root.after(1000, countdown, count-1)
    else:
        for i in range(1, 3):
            sleep(1)
            press("'")
            sleep(0.5)
            type("exec Patch.txt")
            press("enter")
            press("esc")
            press("enter")
            sleep(4)
            press("esc")
            pressMult("down", 4)
            press("enter")
            press("up")
            press("enter")
        sleep(1)
        press("'")
        sleep(0.5)
        type("exec STV.txt")
        press("enter")
        press("esc")
        autoexecB.config(text = "Auto Exec", bg = "red")
def type(text):
    typewrite(text)
def pressMult(key, amount):
    for i in range(1, amount+1):
        press(key)
def autoexec():
    countdown(3)
def info():
    msgbox("Auto Exec: Runs Mods automaticly\nAuto Exit: Exits the game automaticly to the main menu using INSERT\nAuto Reload: Automaticly reloads your gun using LEFT SHIFT")
def exit():
    global count
    count = 1
    press("esc")
    pressMult("down", 4)
    press("enter")
    press("up")
    press("enter")
    sleep(2.1)
    press("enter")
    if choose == "FARM at Hero's Pass":
        sleep(3)
        keyDown("w")
        sleep(0.7)
        keyUp("w")
        keyDown("d")
        sleep(1)
        keyUp("d")
        keyDown("ctrl")
        sleep(0.5)
        press("e")
        keyUp("ctrl")
        count += 1
def reloadslot():
    global allowReload, slot
    while True:
        if allowReload == True:
            break
        slot = str(integerbox("Enter in the weapon's slot to be reloaded"))
        if slot not in ("1","2","3","4"):
            msgbox("A weapon can only be in slot 1, 2, 3 or 4")
        else:
            break
    if allowReload == True:
        allowReload = False
    else:
        allowReload = True
def on_press(event):
    print(event.keysym)
    if event.keysym == "Insert" and allowExit == True:
        print("exit")
        exit()
    if event.keysym == "Shift_L" and allowReload == True:
        print("running reload")
        press(";")
        press("e")
        press(slot)
    print("done")
root = Tk()
root.bind('<KeyPress>', on_press)
root.geometry("378x134")
root.config(bg = "blue")
autoexecB = Button(text = "Auto Exec", bg = "red", font = ("calibri","13"), height = 3, width = 13, command = lambda: autoexec())
autoexitB = Button(text = "Auto Exit", bg = "red", font = ("calibri","13"), height = 3, width = 13)
autoreloadB = Button(text = "Auto Reload", bg = "red", font = ("calibri","13"), height = 3, width = 13, command = lambda: reloadslot())
infoB = Button(text = "INFO", bg = "blue", width = 26, height = 3, command = lambda: info())
exitB = Button(text = "EXIT", bg = "blue", width = 25, height = 3, command = lambda: root.destroy())
autoexecB.place(x = 0, y = 0)
autoexitB.place(x = 126, y = 0)
autoreloadB.place(x = 252, y = 0)
infoB.place(x = 0, y = 78)
exitB.place(x = 193, y = 78)
root.mainloop()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: System doesn't send key/mouse events to any window when it is not active. You need different modules for this. See [pynput - monitoring-the-keyboard](https://pythonhosted.org/pynput/keyboard.html#monitoring-the-keyboard)

Comment: I have tried pynput, however it does not mix well with tkinter mainloop() function. This was my first choice but was forced to be changed to make the program even detect keys pressed while having a tkinter GUI up.

Comment: as I remember few days/weeks ago there was question about pynput with tkinter and it can be resolved but you can't use example from pynput documetation but read more about keyboard listener in pynput - it can run and not block mainloop.

Comment: Could you send me a link?

Comment: I don't remeber link - I only remeber that there was this question because I add answer for this. As I remeber before `mainloop()` you have to create Listener without "with" but `listener = Listener(...)` and use `listener.join()` after `mainloop()`, And you can use `listener.stop()` after `mainloop()` to stop listener.

Comment: Ok, I will try using the listener.join() after mainloop(). the listener = Listen(...) I already tried, but not with the join() after.

Comment: Hey, Nice little weird to work with but should be easy enough. Thanks for the help!

Comment: here my example with link to original question on SO: [pynput-keylogger](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/blob/master/tkinter/pynput-keylogger/main.py). It uses tkinter's Buttons to start and stop Listener which writes keys to file.

Comment: Awesome, It works perfectly and was easy to implement. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> I need a way for tkinter to detect my key presses while not selected

You can't use tkinter for that. It can only detect keyboard events when it has the keyboard focus. You will have to use some platform-specific library to do what you want.